# How to organize general purpose Spring controller functions?

Tags: spring, tomcat, controller, package

I know that many people suggest grouping Spring controllers by page, i.e. "LoginPageController" and "LandingPageController," etc. So the GET handler and other request handlers for the login page are in LoginPageController.

I like this organization most of the time, but lately I'm adding more AJAX functionality, some of which can be reused across many pages and isn't necessarily tied to a single page. I'm wondering what other people are doing in this situation. Maybe make a package for general purpose controllers and try to categorize them in there?

Any advice would be great!

Comment: Can you give some examples of the AJAX functions?

Comment: My webapp has users, who can create a number of "projects." I want to display the project list on a page, and on several pages I may want an AJAX button like "20 More" to display more projects. So I need a URL that will respond with a JSON or XML fragment of the project list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to group by function.  Given your example, I would have a ProjectController that handles both the pages related to Projects as well as the Ajax calls that get/update project data.

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to wish I did this from the start... I had read here: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pageController.html about the Page Controller pattern, which is also referenced in Spring's docs here: http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html Unfortunately this pattern has left me disappointed.